# Ionic black background on view change

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

All of the sudden I am noticing a black background when changing Ionic views. Any idea why this is happening? I managed to capture a screenshot during state change.

[image]

Comment: can u share the scss or did u set any custom css ?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: yes, I will find the code and update with answer

Comment: try this... ion-content, .content-ios {
background:none
}